# How to automate the process of copy pasting certain sections of HTML for a lot of web pages?

Tags: python, html, automation

I want to collect all sections of a web book into a single HTML file to later turn it into an ePUB (eBook) using calibre.

[Here's](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/a-history-of-indian-philosophy-volume-2) the web book. On the web it is organized into a lot of parts. So far I've been copy pasting the relevant HTML sections using chrome devtools to organize it into one HTML file. I think there might be a better way to do it in python (or in any other way).

Answer (score 0):

You may use [this](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) libruary for python to parse and get html codes from any sites like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get('https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/a-history-of-indian-philosophy-volume-2')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")

element = soup.find("a")
source = element.prettify()
```